# What is the correct way of decoding an UIImage within NSCoding protocols initWithCoder: method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage

Please consider the following two `initWithCoding:` method implimentations and assume they belong to a class that contains a single `UIImage` property named `image` that implements the `NSCoding` protocol.

Assuming that `image` was previously encoded, as the `decodeObjectForKey:` method has a return type of `id`, will the first example return a `UIImage` or `NSData` object? Are one of these two examples the correct way of decoding a `UIImage` and initializing it as the property of its class, or is there another way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    image = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kImageKey] retain];
    return self; 
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kImageKey]]; 
    return self; 
}
```

Comment: you should call `[super init]` in your `init` method

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` does not conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, so the second implementation would be the correct one.

Comment: Assuming that the object's `encodeWithCoder:` method had likewise generated data from the original image and fed that to the encoder.

Comment: How can I ensure that encodeWithCoder: generates data, such that when initWithCoderL is called it will feed the data to UIImage's initWithData: method?

Comment: @SamanB: You have to implement both `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`. You, in your implementation of the latter, will generate the data and store it in the archive, for yourself to retrieve in `initWithCoder:`.